# How Can I Modify GRUB?

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

how can i make it so my GRUB does not show safe modes, does show memory sticks, and if possible has a hotkey to boot windows?

Comment: If you do not want to see Safe mode entry...Just install Grub customizer and remove them (but I think it is not good to remove them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to complete the previous reply, here is how you install grub-customizer:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the following line to /etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY=true
```

After that execute `sudo update-grub`.

Answer (score 1):

You can install grub-customizer which is an easy graphical way to make adjustments to your grub menu, including removal of safe modes (which I don't recommend because it may seem like a good idea until something happens and you need to boot into safe mode).

GRUB is located on your fixed storage. Therefore, if your memory stick is bootable, your bios will boot from the memory stick before GRUB ever has a chance to launch from your drive.

Windows will show on the GRUB menu and as far as I know must be selected from the list of installed OSes as normal.

Answer (score -1):

Just Go to the terminal .

Then Log on as Super User.

Then open the File `vi /etc/boot/grub/grub.conf`

There you can modify your grub

I hope it will help you my friend